# SQL syntax error when I try to update long string with non-alphanumeric charcters

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update a string of characters in a table, but the string contains a lot of non-alphanumeric characters. It's causing SSMS to return errors when I try to run the update statement.

I'm running a fairly standard update statement:

```
UPDATE Table
SET TextObj = 'asfsdsad $$%))# asdfas'd #$%^&)asfda'
WHERE ID = 6 AND Name = 'Text'
```

You can see the string I'm trying to update contains a lot of non-alphanumeric characters. I've enclosed the string in single quotes like I would normally do, but SSMS is throwing a syntax error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' Where ID = 6 and Name = 'Text''.

I've also tried double quotes to no avail. How do I get this string updated?

Comment: You have single quote in your string. Escape it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the single quote inside of the string:

```
UPDATE Table
SET TextObj = 'asfsdsad $$%))# asdfas''d #$%^&)asfda'
WHERE ID = 6 AND Name = 'Text'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are escaping the string here? You've just added another single quotation so you close and open new string. Probably won't work.

Comment: @ex4 the second single quote escapes the one in the string

Comment: Ok. To be honest I didn't know that syntax. I would have used `\'` for escaping.  You learn every day.

Comment: I do need the single quote in the string.  Will escaping it with another single quote change the string itself?

Comment: @Steven no ist only tells the sql engine that is not the end of the String

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.  I wasn't aware of the "Escape" concept but it makes complete sense now.